How to get values separated by comma discarding a string before it
Considering the lines
animal1=fish,dog,lion,duck,bee,rabbit,cat    
animal2=turkey,dolphin,bear,goat,tiger    
animal3=elephant,butterfly,alpaca,chicken,horse

We can get the separated words by comma using for example:
(.*?)(?:,|$)

and we'll get (|#| meaning each selection separation):
animal1=fish,|#|dog,|#|lion,|#|duck,|#|bee,|#|rabbit,|#|cat    
animal2=turkey,|#|dolphin,|#|bear,|#|goat,|#|tiger    
animal3=elephant,|#|butterfly,|#|alpaca,|#|chicken,|#|horse

How do I manage to get the separated words, with the multiple selection in each word,
discarding "animal1=", "animal2=" and "animal3="?
fish,|#|dog,|#|lion,|#|duck,|#|bee,|#|rabbit,|#|cat    
turkey,|#|dolphin,|#|bear,|#|goat,|#|tiger    
elephant,|#|butterfly,|#|alpaca,|#|chicken,|#|horse

What I could get so far is to use the negative lookbehind, but it 'anchors' to first occurrence:
(?<=animal\d=).[^,\s]*

Using Sublime Text, simple Find.

can the values themselves contain a = ?

Some context would be interesting. If all your strings looks like the examples and you just want to match each word that's not at the string-start, even \b(?!^)\w+ would work.

It worked too for my example \b(?!^)\w+, thank you!

can the values themselves contain a = ? as for my example, no. It's an array with alphanumerics. The example is like that because the original problem has personal data and I had to create a example and put like this.

The following should work on Sublime text for highlighting all the words you want to match:
(?!.*=)\w+

This matches any word (which implicitly rules out the comma separators) after looking ahead and asserting that there is no = term.  This means that the leading key= will not be matched.

Using Sublime, you could make use of \G
(?:\G(?!^)|^animal\d+=)(\w+),

The pattern matches:

(?: Non capture group for 2 alternatives

\G(?!^) Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string
| Or
^animal\d+= Assert the start of the string, match animal, 1+ digits and =


) Close the non capture group
(\w+) Capture group 1 capture 1+ word chars
, Match a comma

In the replacement use:
$1,|#|

Regex demo
Output
fish,|#|dog,|#|lion,|#|duck,|#|bee,|#|rabbit,|#|cat
turkey,|#|dolphin,|#|bear,|#|goat,|#|tiger
elephant,|#|butterfly,|#|alpaca,|#|chicken,|#|horse


@CasimiretHippolyte Much better, thanks! The lookahead was unnecessary indeed.

At Sublime, simple Find, it highlighted the "animal1" part, for example. Using Sublime Text 4.

@DanielsonAlvesJúnior The pattern captures what you want to keep in group 1, and matches what you don't want to keep. So in Sublime you can use find and replace to get the output with the ,|#| in your question. See https://regex101.com/r/7unGuL/1

@Thefourthbird, I saw at the Regex101, it works perfectly! But at Sublime, I want to highlight at the moment I put the regex on the Find. Not using the replacement at the moment. The main goal is to keep the multiselection available on Sublime! If you put at there, you see that has a different behaviour, I think it might be the flavor configuration.

@DanielsonAlvesJúnior If you want to make sure that animal is there (?:\G(?!^)|^animal\d+=),?\K\w+ See https://regex101.com/r/Ip6alc/1

@Thefourthbird, (?:\G(?!^)|^animal\d+=),?\K\w+ this worked at Sublime! Matched, for my example, only after "animal=" and multiselected the values without the comma.

@DanielsonAlvesJúnior If you need the comma (?:\G(?!^)|^animal\d+=)\K,?\w+ See https://regex101.com/r/OgmRDV/1
